# Syntax error in as_json when using multi level :include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, ruby-on-rails-3.2, to-json

I've got two models that are connected through a third one:

```
Playlist has_many :song_in_playlists, :dependent => :destroy
         has_many :songs, :through => :song_in_playlists

Song has_many :song_in_playlists, :dependent => :destroy
     has_many :playlists, :through => :song_in_playlists
```

The `song_in_playlist` table simply lists the `playlist_id`, `song_id`, as well as a `track_number`.

When calling `/playlists/1.json`, I'd like to get a json hash that holds the playlist's attributes and has another hash inside, which contains the songs (as in `/songs.json` plus the `track_number` from the `song_in_playlists` table entry).

According to [the Rails API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json), I should be able to achieve this doing the following:

```
  def show
    @playlist = Playlist.find(params[:id])
    [...]
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @playlist.as_json(
                           :include => { :song_in_playlists => { 
                              :only => :track_number, :include => :songs { 
                                 :except => [:dropbox_link, :local_path] } } } 
                            ) }
      end
    end
  end
```

However, what I do get is the following:

```
/home/sloth/audiomixer/app/controllers/playlists_controller.rb:30: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting '}'
            :only => :track_number, :include => :songs { 
                                                        ^
/home/sloth/audiomixer/app/controllers/playlists_controller.rb:31: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
              :except => [:dropbox_link, :local_path] } } } 
                                                         ^
/home/sloth/audiomixer/app/controllers/playlists_controller.rb:103: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

So I tried a little less complexity, calling

```
format.json { render json: @playlist.as_json( 
                                :include => song_in_playlists { 
                                   :only => :track_number } ) }
```

but I'm getting a similar error. As soon as I'm putting any braces in between the parentheses, Rails complains, although the API documentation states the opposite.

I really don't know what to try anymore :(

PS: Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.13

**--- EDIT ---**
Okay, I don't really know why but I got this to produce the expected output:

```
format.json { render json: @playlist.as_json( 
                    :include => { :song_in_playlists => { 
                       :include => :song, :only => :track_number } } ) }
```

However, when trying to add `{ :except => [:dropbox_link, :local_path] }` in between `:song` and `, :only`, I'm getting the same errors again..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only partly about rails

```
:include => song_in_playlists {:only => :track_number}
```

just isn't valid ruby syntax

this should be

```
:include => {:song_in_playlists => {:only => :track_number}}
```

Each time, the key is the association name (song_in_playlists) and the value is hash containing one or more of the keys `:only`, `:except` or `:include`

If you want to change what attributes from the songs table are in the json then you need to take

```
format.json { render json: @playlist.as_json( 
                :include => { :song_in_playlists => { 
                   :include => :song, :only => :track_number } } ) }
```

and replace `:song` with a hash that describes what you want to do with song, for example

```
format.json { render json: @playlist.as_json( 
                :include => { 
                  :song_in_playlists => { 
                    :include => {
                      :song => {
                        :except => [:dropbox_link, :local_path]
                      }
                    }, 
                    :only => :track_number 
                  } 
                 })}
```

Comment: Oh my, thanks a lot. I really don't know why I continuously forgot the braces around `:song` although I did it correctly only a few words before for `:song_in_playlists`. Classic :p